# Deploying react app with webpack server

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in ReactJS and was just exploring it and trying to configure it with Webpack and Babel when I experienced an error when I run the application using npm start.

Following are some of files:-

**package.json**

```
{
 "name": "reactstarter",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "A basic React application to explore its state and beauty",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
   },
 "keywords": [
   "reactjs"
  ],
"author": "user1705",
"license": "MIT",

"dependencies": {
 "debug-log": "^1.0.1",
 "react": "^15.3.2",
 "react-dom": "^15.3.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "webpack": "^1.13.2"
 }
}
```

There are two directories *src* directory and *dist* directory inside the root folder.

File: **src/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

  <head>
   <meta charset = "UTF-8">
   <title>React App</title>
  </head>

<body>
  <div id = "app"></div>
  <script src = "/app/bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

File:- **src/app/App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
   return (
     <div>
        Hello World!!!
     </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

File:- **src/app/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

And **webpack.config.js**:-

```
var webpack= require(webpack);
var path= require(path);
var DIST_DIR=path.resolve(__dirname,"dist");

var SRC_DIR= path.resolve(__dirname,"src");

var config={
  entry:SRC_DIR+"/app/index.js",
  output:{
    path:DIST_DIR+"/app",
    fileName:bundle.js,
    publicPath:"/app/",
   },
  devServer: {
  inline: true,
  port: 7777
   },

  modules:{
    loaders:[
        {
            test:/\.js?/,
            include:SRC_DIR,
            loader:"babel-loader",
            query:{
                presets:["react","es2015","stage-2"]
            }
        }
       ]
     }
 };

 module.exports=config;
```

So now whenever I run the command **npm start**,it gives the following error:-
[image]

Being a beginner I have no idea as what is the issue?? If anyone has come across this similar issue or knows about the error,please contribute your knowledge and show me the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you forgot the quotes when you were requiring the npm modules:

```
var webpack= require('webpack');
var path= require('path');
```

Comment: Thanks for the typo but it says bundle is not defined now.I assume bundle.js is a file which will contain all my bundled output in dist directory.

Comment: The same is happening with bundle.js. Wrap it with quotes, too, like this: "bundle.js"

Answer (score 1):

change

```
output:{
    path:DIST_DIR+"/app",
    fileName:bundle.js,
    publicPath:"/app/",
   },
```

to

```
output:{
    path:DIST_DIR+"/app",
    fileName:"bundle.js",
    publicPath:"/app/",
   },
```